# Remove php extension from URL - except one and only one URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this code to remove the .php from the end of my URL's making them more SEF.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

This is generic and works perfectly for every UR but I would like to know how to create **an exception for one and only one URL**, ie: 
`http://www.domain.com/services` to `http://www.domain.com/services.php`
without influencing all the others. Is this possible?

I've tried a simples Redirect but entered a loop.

## ! EDITED !

I failed to mention I have also these rules:

**Add www.**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Remove index** (the extension .php from index has been trimmed already)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So you don't want `/services` to be rewritten as `/services.php` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to explain better.I have my website working as planned everything .php rewritten with out it. I want one and only one URL, in this case services, to have the php extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should :

- add a `RewriteCond`, to disabled `services.php => services`
- add another rule, to enforce `services => services.php`, as the first rule doesn't prevent user to manually use `services` url

**Full `.htaccess`**

```
# domain.tld > www.domain.tld (visible)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# services > services.php (visible)
RewriteRule ^services/?$ services.php [R=301,QSA,L]

# filename > filename.php (transparent)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,NC,L]

# filename.php > filename (visible, exception for services.php)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !services\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# index > /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I just retried it on a blank website and it seems to work. Have you got any other `.htaccess` file/rule ?

Comment: Hi zessx thanks for the input. I do have more rules maybe influencing:  #TO TRANSFORM NON WWW TO WWW #   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]              # AND TO REMOVE THE INDEX  #    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]

Comment: Ok I find my mistake. For the second block, the 2 `RewriteCond` are only applied to the first next `RewriteRule`. See my edit for a working `.htaccess`

Comment: It did work the whole package, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I would believe just a small change in your `.php` removal rule should do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule !^services\.php$ /%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Actually yes, this simples line just did the trick! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where should I mention the one php file in particular that I want the .php to appear on the URL?

Comment: You need to provide the link like, `<a href='http://www.domain.com/services'>Service</a>`, it recognize the service.php automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one rule for each php file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^services  /services.php [L]
```

Comment: Nothing happens on this case

Comment: Sorry, It was "services", not "statistics".

Comment: Thanks Joan I've noticed and I did tried it with the services not the statistics.